# Drop database from WiX installer

Tags: database, wix, wix3.6

The properties `[DATABASE_NAME]` and `[SERVER_NAME]` are defined by the user at installation and it seems like unless they are hard coded then doing this fails:

```
 <Component Id="Component.Sql.Database" Guid="*">
    <sql:SqlDatabase 
      Id="Sql.Database" 
      Database="[DATABASE_NAME]"
      Server="[SERVER_NAME]" 
      CreateOnInstall="yes" 
      DropOnUninstall="yes"
      ContinueOnError="no"
      ConfirmOverwrite="yes" />
</Component>
```

The bit that is supposed to drop the db is `DropOnUninstall="yes"`

I've found a post on the WiX user group suggesting the following approach to dropping the database on uninstall:

```
  <Component Id="Component.Sql.DropDatabase" Guid="146CD264-1F6D-4E19-BFCC-E544F5BD2D6C">
    <sql:SqlString
      Id="Sql.DropDatabase"
      SqlDb="Sql.Master"
      Sequence="1000"
      ExecuteOnInstall="no"
      ExecuteOnUninstall="yes"
      ExecuteOnReinstall="no"
      ContinueOnError="no"
      SQL="DROP DATABASE [\[][DATABASE_NAME]\[]]"/>
  </Component>

  <Fragment>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="Sql.Master" Database="master" Server="[SERVER_NAME]" />
  </Fragment>
```

The idea being that at uninstall the `DROP DATABASE ...` command is executed on the `master` database on the server. However this SQL statement never gets executed on the server.

The MSIEXEC log doesn't seem to give any information and I get no errors.

Has anyone successfully achieved this (before I write a custom action to do this)?

I've tried copying the database name and server to the registry to cache them, but this hasn't helped.

Comment: Do you cache the DATABASE_NAME and SERVER_NAME property anywhere during installation, e.g. the registry? You might need to extend the uninstaller to re-read this property from local state during uninstallation otherwise the value will just be null or the default from the Property table and it won't work.

Comment: I've tried caching them in the registry. That seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
    xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"  <!-- Need to import this -->
    xmlns:sql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension"><!-- Need to import this -->


<sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" 
             Database="TestDatabase" 
             Server="[SQLSERVER]" 
             DropOnUninstall="yes" 
             User="SQLUser">
```

This will definitely work.....